# Execute Action<T> after dequeuing

Tags: c#

I'm writing a simple TCP server based upon the example [here](https://gist.github.com/leandrosilva/656054#file-server-cs).
Instead of echoing the received data I want to keep the socket open to send and receive more data.

Hence, I changed some functions as follow:

```
public readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action<String>> actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action<String>>();

public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    allDone.Set();

    Connected.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    StateObject state = new StateObject
    {
        workSocket = handler
    };
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

    while (handler.Connected)
    {
        if (actions.TryDequeue(out Action<String> action))
        {
            try
            {
                action(/* ??? */);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(0); 
    }
}

public void SendData(String data)
{
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}
```

in the external thread I enqueue my data:

```
 String data = "something";
 server.actions.Enqueue((x) => server.SendData(data));
```

I don't understand how to retrieve the "data" value, after dequeuing the Action. "action" is actually a Action, but when I try to invoke it:

```
action();
```

the compiler says:

> Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'obj' of 'Action'.

It's clear I didn't pass the argument, but I cannot understand where and how I should retrieve it.

Comment: maybe you want the queue up the string and just call the same action<string> or method?

Comment: get rid of the the x in (x)

Comment: It might work, but it seems a workaround to me. I passed the "data" parameter in the lambda expression. Where has it gone?

Comment: when you call it, then pass null since the x isn't used

Comment: Doesn't compile: The delegate Action<string> doesn't accept argument 0

Comment: what about Action without the argument

Comment: @kenny it works, thanks! But I didn't learn how to retrieve the values from an Action...

Comment: I think you want to make the string receive the argument of you Action<string>, but ... don't have the high level details. Good luck

Comment: What's wrong in my question to deserve a downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
server.actions.Enqueue((x) => server.SendData(data));
```

You are already capturing `data` in the closure, why the need of the argument `x`? Simply store an action that will invoke `server.SendData(data)`:

```
server.actions.Enqueue(() => server.SendData(data));
```

Of course, you need to change the type of `actions` accordingly:

```
public readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> actions =
    new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
```

And now you can invoke the action like you want to: `action()`.